# Как с базы данных взять картинку и сохранить себе на компьютер

Tags: c#, база-данных, sqlite

Есть база данных sqlite, в ней есть колонка photo. Мне нужно из базы взять картинку и сохранить себе на компьютер (в папку). Есть  следующий код:

```
private void getImage(string file)
{
    string query = "SELECT photo FROM Tasks WHERE id=" + list_comments[i];
    SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(query, db);

    try
    {
        IDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        try
        {
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                byte[] a = (System.Byte[])rdr[0];
                ByteToImage(a, file);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc) { /*MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);*/ }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { /*MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);*/ }
}

public void ByteToImage(byte[] imageBytes, string fileName)
{
    // Convert byte[] to Image
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
    ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
    System.Drawing.Image image = new Bitmap(ms);
    //pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    image.Save(fileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

Но он не работает. Как правильно реализовать?

Comment: Как именно не работает? Выдаёт ошибку? Ничего нк сохраняет?

Comment: А как картинка попала в БД? В каком формате она была изначально?

Comment: Если у вас картинка хранится в базе в бинарном виде, то зачем вам бинарный вид преобразовывать в Bitmap? Сохраняйте байт массив в файл с необходимым расширением и всё.

Comment: не очень удобно в байтах хранить лучше хранить картинку на сервере в папке а в базе ее адрес и просто скачивать по адересу